# How to assign the output of a java method into a bash script variable

Tags: java, bash, variables, sh

I have a bash script that calls a java class method.   The method returns a string to the linux console when run independently.  how can I assign the value from the java method to a variable in a bash script?

running the script:

```
java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter]
```

output:  `my_string`

if added in a bash script:

```
read parameter
java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter] | read the_output
echo $the_output
```

the above doesnt work, I also tried unsuccessfully:

```
the_output=java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter]
the_output=`java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter]`
java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter] 2>&1
```

How can i get the output stored into the_output variable?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bash:

```
$ the_output="$(java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter])"
```

See: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

**EDIT**:
Actually, looking at your command-line, I'm surprised that it works.  I haven't seen a Java program called like that before.  Usuallly you can only run a main() method from a java command.  How does yours work?

**EDIT**:
You say that you are still getting output going to the console when you do this.  You may need to capture stderr too:

```
  $ the_output="$(java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter] 2>&1 )"
```

`2>` means redirect stderr (file descriptor 2). `&1` means to the same place as stdout (file descriptor 1) is going.

Comment: when I run this command i get the output "my_string" in the console but the echo $the_output returns empty.

Comment: That will happen if your java program writes to System.err rather than System.out. In that case, you need to get Bash capture stderr as well.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! the last one works!
the_output="$(java -cp /opt/my_dir/class.method [parameter] 2>&1 )"

Comment: You actually don't need the outer quotes here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) by wrapping your command in backquotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try **bashj** (a bash mutant with java support) https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/.

for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
X= Math.cos(0.5)
Y= Math.hypot(3.0,4.0)
Z= System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")
```

You can also put your own methods in a jar loaded by bashj, or include some java source code within the bashj script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
#!java
public static int factorial(int n) 
{if (n<=0) return(0);
 if (n==1) return(1);
 return(n*factorial(n-1));}
#@bash
echo j.factorial(10)
```

This is **much faster** than any solution involving the creation of a new JVM process.